# What is the formula to calculate the yearly amount of a step up SIP?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, finance

So,
I recently learned how to use google sheets and apply formulas and functions to the cells. I decided to make my own step up SIP calculator on google sheets. Here's the link:

[My spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ghfXtEEdvpDQBYEUyw_L4nFgIRRijMArNPmm1pQMDmo/edit?usp=sharing)

I used the basic formula that came to my mind, but the resultant amount calculated in my spreadsheet is not the same as what I get from using a online step up SIP calculator like finology:

[Finology step up SIP calculator](https://www.finology.in/Calculators/Invest/StepUp-Calculator.aspx)

If anyone can give me the formula it would be really helpful.

If u open the spreadsheet, you can see the formula I used for the calculation of yearly amount, but, it is wrong for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

P as the initial investment amount
r as the annual interest rate (expressed as a decimal)
n as the number of compounding periods in a year
t as the number of years

The future value of the investment (FV) can be calculated using the formula for compound interest:

FV = P *(1 + r/n)n * t

[SIP Calculator](https://www.cashmeasure.com/) Tool